# Flutter slide with inner arrows

Tags: flutter, widget, carousel, flutter-pageview

How can I achieve such behavior in Flutter? any widget or plugins example?

[See this gif](http://g.recordit.co/Bbklr61X7E.gif)

I tried [carousels](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) plugins and viewPagers widgets but couldn't make it work.

here is the sample code I started with.

```
CarouselSlider(
   items: [
        Container(child: Text("Complimentary"), width: double.infinity),
        Container(child: Text("Complimentary"), width: double.infinity),
        Container(child: Text("Complimentary"), width: double.infinity),
        Container(child: Text("Complimentary"), width: double.infinity),
        Container(child: Text("Complimentary"), width: double.infinity),
   ],
   options: CarouselOptions(
        height: 39 * resizeFactor,
        autoPlay: false,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
        autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 10),
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using both Swiper and Row of arrows, with the following code:

```
      Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 39 * resizeFactor,
            child: Swiper(
              itemCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => getIndexWidget(index), // -> Text widget.
              viewportFraction: 0.4,
              onIndexChanged: (value) {
                setState(() => carouselIndex = value);
              },
              loop: false,
              controller: swiperController,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30 * resizeFactor),
            height: 39 * resizeFactor,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                getIndicatorWidget(false),  // back arrow icon.
                getIndicatorWidget(true),   // forward arrow icon.
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: where did you get ```getIndicatorWidget``` from?

Comment: it's just the right/left arrow widget.. @ajnabz

Comment: oh for some reason it gives me an error saying I need to declare it